# LibreOffice: soffice/oosplash start permission denied error

Tags: openbsd, libreoffice

Few days after installed OpenBSD, I got the following error:

```
$ libreoffice                                                                  
/usr/local/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice[171]: /usr/local/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash: Permission denied
$
```

Same even with root. oosplash has execute permissions:

```
$ ls -lah /usr/local/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  bin  46.2K Oct  2 22:52 /usr/local/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash
$ 
$ cat -n /usr/local/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice | tail -1
   171  exec $RRCHECK $VALGRINDCHECK $STRACECHECK "$sd_prog/oosplash" "$@"
$
```

I am using the following versions:

```
$ pkg_info | grep libreoffice
libreoffice-5.2.7.2p6v0 multi-platform productivity suite
$ 
$ uname -mrs
OpenBSD 6.2 amd64
$
```

**The Q**: how can I debug the problem with LibreOffice?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48631646/why-does-libreoffice-wants-memory-pages-to-be-writable-and-executable-in-the-sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binaries of LibreOffice are installed in `/usr/local`. You need to add `wxallowed` (as mount option) in `/etc/fstab` to the partition which contains the directory `/usr/local`.

Comment: yes :) this was the problem, I forgot that for hardening reasons, I removed the wxallowed, but didn't it worked before without it?

Comment: I don't remember when the `wxallowed` option was enforced but there was a release which only showed a warning in the dmesg.

Comment: it was enforced from 6.0: https://www.openbsd.org/faq/upgrade60.html - things are getting better :) only some ports, ex.: LibreOffice, Google Chrome has security problems regarding W^X..